# Am I facing overflow?

Tags: css, flexbox

The following code is for learning porpuses:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class1{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.class2{
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.class3{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
            <div class='class2'>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Questions:

1. ***Why*** the black rectangle doesn't contain all the red rectangles horizontally?
2. ***Why*** the bottom of the black rectangle doesn't end in the last red rectangle in that column? (I know why there is no room for an extra red rectangle - that's not the question).
3. ***How*** can I make the black rectangle cover all the red rectangles horizontally while keeping `flex-direction: column;` in `class2`? (without removing `height: 100vh`)

***Note:*** The first two questions have more priority so please don't post an answer with only a code. it's useless.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the black rectangle doesn't contain all the red rectangles?

Because the element is using `flex-wrap: wrap;` with `flex-direction: column;`.

From [the doc about using CSS flex-direction property with column option](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp):

> The flexible items are displayed vertically, as a column

Since the parent div doesn't provide `height` value *enough* to wrap all items, it will stop at that.

> Why the bottom of the black rectangle doesn't end in the last red rectangle in that column?

That's 'cause of the parent div height. It's not *enough*.

> How can I make the black rectangle cover all the red rectangles?

Removing `height: 100vh;` property from `class1`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class1{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
}

.class2{
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.class3{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
            <div class='class2'>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class1{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 167px;
}

.class2{
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 201px;
    height: 166px;
}

.class3{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
            <div class='class2'>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class1{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 87px;
}

.class2{
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 393px;
    height: 86px;
}

.class3{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
            <div class='class2'>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
                <div class='class3'>1111</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1. Do you mean that `flex-wrap: wrap;` is only good for horizontal overflow? (I wanted to have the same effect when using `flex-wrap: wrap;` with `flex-direction: row;`). 2. I'm aware that there is no more room for an extra red rectangle. I asked - then why the black rectangle doesn't end before? I didn't provide height so the value of the height can be dynamic. 3. I asked how to solve it when there is a height: 100vh.   ----- Maybe I wasn't clear. I updated my question.

Comment: @StavAlfi You need to provide the value `width` and `height` of class `class2` while using `flex-direction` (both `column` and `row`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. np, I will define height but I want the width to be dynamic because I don't know how many red rectangles I will have.

Comment: Ahh, if you use it with option `column`, you can leave the height value. Otherwise, if you use it with `row` option, you can leave the width value. We set both of the values to fit the content on your site